# Require user login in GWT with web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, authentication, web.xml

I develop an application with GAE and GWT where the user has to be logged in with his Google Account when he access the site. So I defined the following in the web.xml file...

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I'm running the local dev server I get promted with the test login-screen when I open the app the first time, but when I deploy it, I directly come to my application without any authentication. 
First I thought, that could be, because I'm already logged in to other Google services, but I tried it in other browsers and in incognito mode too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying one is to use the URL pattern to * so that all your resources are secure and  secondly addind `web-resource-name`  tag to "all" value, as shown in code snippet below.

And I am assuming you already have servlet mapping to service etc

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: But this will affect other Servlets as well, right? Because I have a Servlet which receives POST-Requests from an Android device. Do you have any suggestions how to authorize the phone ?

Comment: If the phone is accessing through browser, then it would be same as a PC auth. But if an Android App is accessing then I am not sure how login will work. I am sure there is a way, but don't know how, you can check on Android forum. Also you can separate out URLs being accessed by Android and not apply auth to them, if that's your requirement.

Comment: The Android client has to be authorized with the Google Account too. So it would be really nice if I could send a  "authorized" POST Request. I'm going to ask some Googlers and try your solution tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure that it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The problem was, that I set the url pattern to ProjectName.html. It worked on the dev server, because the url is Projectname.html?codesrv="" or some other parameters. But on appspot the url is just projectname.appspot.com